Connect laravel project with mongo atlas
I'm trying to connect my laravel project with mongo atlas, before that everything with mongo was OK as a localhost.
MongoDB\Driver\Exception\ConnectionTimeoutException 

No suitable servers found (`serverSelectionTryOnce` set): [TLS handshake failed: error:14094438:SSL routines:ssl3_read_bytes:tlsv1 alert internal error calling he

1   C:\Users\project\vendor\mongodb\mongodb\src\functions.php:487
    MongoDB\Driver\Manager::selectServer(Object(MongoDB\Driver\ReadPreference))

2   C:\Users\project\vendor\mongodb\mongodb\src\Database.php:427
    MongoDB\select_server(Object(MongoDB\Driver\Manager), [])`

In database.php file:
'mongodb' => [
    'driver' => 'mongodb',
    'dsn' => env('DB_URI', 'mongodb+srv://username:password@database.1tgotqv.mongodb.net/?retryWrites=true&w=majority&appName=myapp'),
    'database' =>  env('DB_DATABASE', 'homestead'),
],

In .env file:
DB_URI=mongodb+srv://username:password@database.1tgotqv.mongodb.net/?retryWrites=true&w=majority&appName=myapp
DB_CONNECTION=mongodb
DB_PORT=27017


check if any of this works.
